# address.transfer not working

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract ApprovalContract {
address public sender;
address public receiver;

address public constant approver = 0x5AEDA56215b167893e80B4fE645BA6d5Bab767DE;

constructor() public {
// tbd
}
function deposit(address _receiver) external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0);
    sender = msg.sender;
    receiver = _receiver;
}

function viewApprover() external pure returns(address){
    return(approver);
}

function viewRe() external pure returns(address){
    return(receiver);
}


function approve() external payable{
    require(msg.sender == approver);

    receiver.transfer(address(this).balance); // this line not working

}
}
```

I am getting transfer variable not visible.

> Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent
>   lookup in address.

Answer (score 17):

Use

```
address payable public receiver;
```

in declaration for the addresses you are looking to transfer Ether in contract. As per the solidity documentation:

> The address type comes in two flavours, which are largely identical:
>
> `address`: Holds a 20 byte value (size of an Ethereum address).
>
> `address payable`: Same as address, but with the additional members transfer and
>   send. The idea behind this distinction is that address payable is an
>   address you can send Ether to, while a plain address cannot be sent
>   Ether.

Comment: That's true in Solidity 0.5.x, but the original code in the question appears to be using Solidity 0.4.x, where `address payable` does not yet exist. That said, the original code compiles fine in 0.4.x modulo a `pure` that should be a `view`. So I don't know which compiler version is actually being used. :-)

Comment: IMO only case in which error can appear is when compiler is 0.5.0. @sumeet Please clarify it

Comment: Just because it says `pragma solidity ^0.4.23;` doesn't mean it's using that version. If the contract is being imported into another contract that has a 0.5.0 compiler version, then it'll be compiled with 0.5.0 and throw this error.

Answer (score 4):

You can always cast `address` to `payable address`:

```
address(uint160(receiver)).transfer(...);
```

Comment: it says `DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.`

Answer (score 0):

You can try these... Just by changing last line.

```
 function approve() external {
require(msg.sender == approver);
address(this).balance;
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me following this code..

```
function approve() external payable{
    require(msg.sender == approver);

  address(uint160(receiver)).transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the original receiver declaration to:

```
    address payable public receiver;
```

Then I changed the "receiver.transfer..." to:

```
     address(uint160(receiver)).transfer(address(this).balance);
```

I still got an error that said:

> Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable.
> receiver = _receiver;

So I changed the "function deposit..." declaration to:

```
    function deposit(address payable _receiver) external payable{
```

And now it works!

My overall code now looks like this

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

contract ApprovalContract {

    address public sender;
    address payable public receiver;
    address public constant approver = (your own test address);

    function deposit(address payable _receiver) external payable{
        require(msg.value > 0);
        sender = msg.sender;
        receiver = _receiver;
    }

    function viewApprover() external pure returns(address) {
        return(approver);
    }

    function approve() external {
        require(msg.sender == approver);
        address(uint160(receiver)).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `address public receiver` to `address payable receiver`.