# Getting TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address"

Tags: solidity

Working on [this Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/ethereum-and-solidity-the-complete-developers-guide/) for Ethereum and i keep getting the error mentioned in the title of the question.

For reference i have checked out the answers on questions: [1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71504/solidity-send-and-transfer-are-only-available-for-objects-of-type-address), [2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71766/solidity-error-address-address-payable) and [3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63618/address-transfer-not-working). But the error persists.

The contract goes like this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;

    constructor() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);

        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, now, players)));
    }

    function pickWinner() public {
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        players[index].transfer(address(this).balance); // Where the error happens
    }
}
```

Using Remix Solidity compiler.

I am pretty sure this is some old version code error since the Solidity version used in the course is ^0.4. Can anyone guide me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because your `players` address needs to be `payable`, like that:

```
address payable[] public players;
```

If you update your code to Solidity version `0.6.0`, you can convert from `address` to `address payable` via `payable(x)`, like that:

```
payable(players[index]).transfer(address(this).balance);
```

From the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/060-breaking-changes.html#new-features):

> Conversions from `address` to `address payable` are now possible via
>   `payable(x)`, where `x` must be of type `address`.